# PID for keeping heading, for combat robot, how to handle sudden multiple rotations

Tags: control-engineering, robotics, software

I'm building a beetleweight class (mass 3 lbs) combat robot, it will use two wheels for tank-style drive and a horizontal spinner weapon. This robot will serve as an experimental platform, I want to see if I can get better control if I implement an IMU, the robot will not be given commands like "turn left" or "turn right", instead, it will get "keep heading 37 degrees", and the remote control has a quadrature encoder on it to give commands in that fashion. If I rotate the encoder 90 degrees, the robot should also rotate 90 degrees. I am hoping this makes the same competitive difference between playing a first-person-shooter video game with a joystick vs with a mouse.

I have coded a classic PID controller, which is fine, that's not hard for me. But I believe a simple PID controller is not optimal for this kind of robot. Hear me out:

This is a combat robot with a horizontal weapon. It is very likely that weapon impact, either from me or from an opponent, will cause the whole robot to suddenly spin multiple times.

The problem is, my robot is now spinning very fast. What should the PID do? Should it take advantage of the momentum? Or fight the momentum? How does it choose?

The ideal goal is to point at the target heading in the least amount of time as possible, it might mean "in the least number of spins" but that's not necessary.

(note that in this event, it is likely that the wheels have no traction, but I'd still like them to start spinning earlier)

With the most basic PID controller implementation, I think the output will just be oscillating.

One of the things I've done is to clear the integral accumulated whenever the error and prev_error flips signs, this way at least the output doesn't get too much unnecessary contribution from the I term when the error goes from 180 deg to -180 deg (this might sound wrong, but at 180 degrees, the P term will saturate the output anyways, no need for I)

My next strategy is to simply disable PID controller if the robot is spinning too fast. Above a certain spin-rate threshold, it will only attempt to counter-rotate, not caring about what the target angle is. (the threshold is probably just the fastest achievable spin-rate if all wheels had traction and at maximum speed)

Those are my two strategies, what other strategies am I missing? Are there any dual PID controllers that can calculate two opposing commands and then extrapolate into the future to see which output is better? Or something else?

Thanks

Comment: PID is fine.  Just aim for desired heading+K*360deg where K is some integer you decide with some logic and sensor input. You can also apply PID to get a desired angular acceleration, angular velocity, etc instead of desired heading during those spins.

Comment: Agreed, pid should be fine for this. Try it, and then add a few fixes for problems which prop up and you should be good. It won't oscillate if your D factor is tuned properly.

Comment: You could run 2 loops, one for each rotational direction, and use the output that will result in settling in the shortest time (you will need an additional predictive model).

Comment: I would ask this in #building-questions on https://discord.gg/oota